# Change of variable mu=cos(theta)

Tags: sympy

I would like to make a change a variable in my equations such as mu=cos(theta).
I tried to find a solution but I didn't find one. And I tried to build my own function by using replace for all the functions but it didn't work for n-derivative and it's quite long to take an array of all the functions as input.

The functions are multivariables and the derivative order is max 3

Example :

```
a=sy.Function('a')(zeta,theta,phi)
b=sy.Function('b')(zeta,theta,phi)

expr=sy.Derivative(a,theta,2)+sy.Derivative(b,theta)+sy.Derivative(a,phi)

#I would like to obtain something like that 

expr=-(mu*sy.Derivative(a,mu,2)+(mu**2-1)*sy.Derivative(a,mu)+mu*sy.Derivative(b,mu))+sy.Derivative(a,phi)
```

Thank you for your help